# Add tags to git in Aptana

Tags: git, aptana

Can someone tell me if it's possible to add git tags to my commits in Aptana 3 on mac?
If so can you tell me how do do it than?

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't have any specific support for managing tags in git. However adding something to list, describe, add, push tags would be pretty straightforward. Can you file a ticket asking for the specific tag functionality you're looking to be able to perform inside Aptana? http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

For now, the "workaround" is to run the command by hand inside the Terminal view or using git outside the IDE.